# Telescopic localisation of Eilenberg-MacLane spaces

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, stable-homotopy

Fix a prime $p$ and an integer $n>0$.  Let $K$ be the corresponding Morava $K$-theory spectrum, and let $T$ be the telescope of a $v_n$-self map of a finite spectrum of type $n$, and let $X$ be the Eilenberg-MacLane space $B^{n+1}(\mathbb{Z}/p)$.  It is well-known that $\widetilde{K}_*(B)=0$, or equivalently that the map $L_KS^0\to L_K\Sigma^\infty X_+$ is an equivalence of $E_\infty$ ring spectra.  Is it also true that $\widetilde{T}_*(B)=0$, or equivalently that the map $L_TS^0\to L_T\Sigma^\infty X_+$ is an equivalence?  This would of course follow from the Telescope Conjecture (TC), but due to Burklund, Hahn, Levy and Schlank we now know that that TC is not true in general.  Bousfield conjectured a positive answer to my question in 1994; at that time he believed that Ravenel had succeeded in disproving TC in general, but he still believed that this special case might hold.  It may be that Proposition 4.1 of the paper "[Chromatic cyclotomic extensions](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2103.02471.pdf)" (by Carmeli, Schlank and Yanovski) points to a proof, but I have not sufficiently understood the framework of definitions to be sure about that.  If so, it would be nice to have a more self-contained proof.

Comment: This also appears in Thm 5.3.5 of [another Carmeli-Schlank-Yanovski paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1811.02057) (Ambidexterity in Chromatic Homotopy theory). In fact, the theorem there is a more general statement but happily the proof proceeds by reducing to the case of your question. I think the proof there is similarly entwined with general ambidexterity theory, though.

Comment: It is important to note that their framework allows them to *reduce* the question from T to K

Comment: (And so it ultimately boils down to the same Ravenel-Wilson calculation + framework)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two inputs needed to show this:

1. The Ravenel-Wilson and Johnson-Wilson calculations;
2. Ambidexterity theory

(2) is used to to reduce the question to (1). Note that in Hopkins and Lurie's [original account](https://people.math.harvard.edu/%7Elurie/papers/Ambidexterity.pdf) of ambidexterity, one needed to get into the weeds of the calculations to do this. In the later theory of [Carmeli-Schlank-Yanovski](https://arxiv.org/abs/1811.02057), besides porting everything to the $T(n)$-local setting the argument was also improved so that the only calculational input needed was the $K(n)$-Euler characteristics of the Eilenberg-MacLane spaces.

Amusingly, it's [now possible](https://arxiv.org/abs/2310.00275) (see discussion after Example 9) to compute these Euler characteristics without using the RW/JW calculations at all! (The price for this second reduction is relying on some more general theory including the chromatic Nullstellensatz and some descent theory for chromatically localized algebraic $K$-theory.)

To amplify: **ambidexterity theory is not really that fearsome** -- the fearsome part of the original Hopkins-Lurie work was their reworking of the RW/JW calculations -- the ambidexterity part is much more conceptual. And the dependence on fearsome computational input has been reduced quite a bit now.

---

If you want to be as low-tech as possible, then you can at least get something in the ballpark. As noted in [Carmeli-Schlank-Yanovski](https://arxiv.org/abs/1811.02057) (see discussion after Theorem E), it already follows from Theorem 3.1 (even Lemma 3.5) of Bousfield's [On Homology Equivalences and Homological Localizations of Spaces](https://doi.org/10.2307/2374082) that $L_{T(n)} K(\mathbb Z/p, m) = 0$ for *some* $m$, but with no bound on $m$ seemingly deducible.

The argument is much shorter and more elementary (it's a basically self-contained 10 page paper, and this result is near the beginning!): Bousfield shows for any spectrum $E$ that

- If $L_E K(\mathbb Z/p,m) \neq 0$ for all $m$, then $L_E = L_{HE_\ast}$ (where these localization functors are defined on *spaces*).

Since $L_{T(n)}$ kills type $n+1$ spaces, unlike $L_{HT(h)_\ast}$, we conclude that $L_{T(h)} K(\mathbb Z/p, m)  =0$ for some $m$. By closure of acyclics under colimits, this is also true for larger $m$.

The proof of the bulleted statement boils down to the fact that if $X \to Y$ is an $E_\ast$-equivalence, then so is $SP(X) \to SP(Y)$ where $SP$ is the functor from the Dold-Thom theorem.

**EDIT:** Looking at the proof, I think what one gets is that $\tilde T(n)_\ast K(C_p, m) = 0$ as soon as there exists a finite type $n+1$ space with connectivity $\leq m$. Bounding this $m$ is I believe still an open question.